# What is better option to loop obj or set it as array and loop it as array?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am working on small project. I got array with 8 objects from mongo.
(8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
But I want to select in one page only 2 objects.

I think 2 small obj will be easy use on one page, but what if obj will be huge?
I am thinking for this 2 solutions, I would like to get your opinion what is better or show me better solution.

```
        const [data, setData]=useState([])
        const [obj1, setObj1]=useState({})
        const [obj2, setObj2]=useState({})
 
      const fetchData = async () => {
       const x = []

       const res = await axios('/api/getTeam/SVK_CZ')
       const mongo = res.data
       console.log(mongo)   // (8) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
       x.push(mongo[0]
       x.push(mongo[1]
       setData(x)    // it give me array with 2 obj. I can use map()

      // or

       setObj1(mogno[0])
       setObj2(mongo[1])  // but I cannot loop it and I have to use 2 divs.
                         // there are small object but if it will be big , I dont know.
}
```

Please let me know if there is esiest solution. THANK YOU

Comment: `setData(mongo.slice(0, 2))` is simpler.

Comment: "but what if obj will be huge" - Well the object's size isn't going to change regardless of whether you put it into an array.

Comment: Assuming if you use array and your `.map` has appropriate `key` etc, the performance should be fine for both. Also: https://xkcd.com/1691/